# What does "Miezekatze" mean, and how is it different from simply "Katze"?

Tags: meaning, difference

According to the leo dictionary it translates to "pussycat", but I'm not sure what exactly this word specifies. So what does "Miezekatze" mean?

- Is it a (group of) particular breed(s) of cats?
- Is it a particulary cute or otherwise out-of-the-ordinary cat?
- Is it only a cat that is kept as a pet?
- Is it something else?

Comment: Eine vorzugsweise _weibliche_, (besonders geliebte?) Katze. Just like the English intention in _pussycat_. :3

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Falsch. Das Wort "Katze" ist generische Femininum und wird zum Beispiel in "Katzenfutter", "Katzenkorb" und "Katzenjammer" benutzt. Über das Geschlecht des Tieres ist damit nur dann etwas gesagt, wenn unmittelbar davor oder danach auch von Katern die Rede ist. Wie bei der Fußgängerampel.

Comment: Die Miezekatze verhält sich zur Katze wie der Brummbär zum Bären.

Answer (score 7):

Did you check dictionaries? [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Miezekatze) says:

> Katze; Kater; (familiär)

The intention is to convey a familiar, dear tone. You can perfectly well say:

> Der blöde, fette Kater des Nachbarn...

but it would be odd to use Miezekatze.

Even clearer is [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM04748#XGM04748)‘s explanation under the entry MIEZ:

> …dergleichen lockrufe, lautmalend nach der stimme des thieres; es hat sich nachher als schmeichelname der katze selbst ergeben, die miez und die mieze, auch verdeutlichend die miezekatze

Hence we can say it is the merging of the onomatopoeic endearment *Miez* and the clarifying *Katze*.

Comment: _"but it would be odd to use Miezekatze."_ Well, [Tweety](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XWgRg7NV78) might use that idiomatically :3

Comment: Ooops I've used that in a completely different context either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ awesome find! ;) But of course verifies the above, because the above is what makes it funny.

Answer (score 5):

"Katze" is a neutral, formally usable word to mean about any kind of feline that isn't a Grosskatze and/or Raubkatze (Tigers, Lions and the lot). It can also explicitly mean a female cat vs a Kater (the same way one can differentiate cat and tomcat in English).

"Mieze" and "Miezekatze" are informal, endearing, possibly diminutive terms for cats - and also have potential to be misunderstood as a term of endearment, and where it would be inappropriate also as a sexist slur!,  if used in the wrong context.

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you know an example text that uses Mieze/-katze as sexist slur?

Comment: Do not google image search for "Geile Miezen", unless it is NOT literal pussycats you are looking for.

Comment: Lol Actually I never searched for _geile Miezen_ - maybe that's why I didn't know the expression. And I wonder, whether _Pornodeutsch_ exists as a research area among linguists ;)

Comment: Je nach Situation kann "Miezekatze" ebenso gut als charmantes Kosewort verstanden werden.

Comment: That's why I said "where it would be inappropriate"

Answer (score 2):

Den Kommentar von Userunknown zur Eingangsfrage (dass Miezekatze sich zur Katze verhalte wie Brummbär zum Bären) aufgreifend:

Man könnte behaupten, dass das Voranstellen der onomatopoetischen Wiedergabe einer für das Tier typischen Lautäußerung dazu dient, den Eindruck der stereotypen Charakteristika dieses Tieres zu verstärken.

> Miezekatze

sage ich, wenn ich das Süßkatzenhafte einer Katze betonen will.

> Brummbär

sage ich, wenn ich das Dickbärenhafte eines Bären betonen will.

> Muhkuh

sage ich, wenn ich das Gemütlichkühische der Kuh betonen will.

So gesehen bewirken die vorangestellen Lautäußerungen eine Verstärkung des Bildes durch Überzeichnung. In der graphischen Kunst würde man von einer Karikatur sprechen.

Außerdem ist damit jedesmal ein positiver Affekt verbunden. Ich demonstriere durch diese Wortwahl, dass ich dem fraglichen Tier gegenüber positive Gefühle hege; oder dass ich mein Gegenüber auffordern will, dem Tier gegenüber solche positiven Gefühle zu hegen.

Außerdem signalisiere ich, dass ich mein Gesprächsgegenüber für ein sehr kleines Kinde halte; oder dass ich unser Verhältnis so einschätze, dass ich es mir erlauben kann, im Gespräch aus welchen Gründen auch immer - etwa zum Zwecke der Ironie - auf Elemente der Kleinkindersprache zurückzugreifen.

Auf jeden Fall geht es hier um den emotional-expressiven Anteil sprachlicher Ausdrücke.

Allerdings sind es nicht immer Lautäußerungen, die zur karikierenden Verstärkung dienen. Der

> Wackeldackel

greift physiologische Charakteristika des Tieres auf. Der

> Blubberfisch

versucht, den offensichtlichen Mangel an Lautgebungsinventar durch andere mit dem Tier verbundene (oder als verbunden imaginierte) akustische Phänome zu kompensieren.

Comment: Der Deutung von *Wackeldackel* kann ich nicht zustimmen, der sieht m. E. [so](https://goo.gl/images/QednGu) aus.

Comment: Ja, ich weiß, der Wackeldackel hat eine andere Primärbedeutung und Alltagsverwendung...